# I'm looking for an alternative to achieve this in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am a beginner in XSLT. This is my XSL sample:

```
<xsl:when test="/can/be/a/very/long/location/path/@value > 0 ">
    <xsl:value-of select="/can/be/a/very/long/location/path/@value" />
</xsl:when>
```

It seems like the `<value-of select="...">` can be more concise. How could that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular example you can simply write:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/can/be/a/very/long/location/path/@value[. > 0]" />
```

which outputs nothing if no value is selected

Comment: nice, what does the period mean in this case?

Comment: It refers to the context item. The predicate within the square brackets is like a function that's applied to every item in the selected sequence to return true or false, and "." is the argument to the function, that is, the item being tested.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done like this -

```
<xsl:variable name="location" select="/can/be/a/very/long/location/path/@value"/>

<xsl:if test="$location">
    <xsl:value-of select="$location" />
</xsl:if>
```

`<xsl:when>` is mostly used when you have multiple conditions and the correct way to do this is

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="condition1"> </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="condition2"> </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="condition3"> </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise> </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use an `<xsl:template>` with a predicate for this task:

```
<xsl:template match="/can/be/a/very/long/location/path[@value &gt; 0]">
  <xsl:value-of select="@value" />      <!-- current axis is 'path' -->
</xsl:template>
```